# What is the correct way to use Axios Create With Multipart and FormData in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I want to separate the config and the post from axios with react native using multipart upload.

Example :

```
let param = {file: fileObject.uri, mimeType: fileObject.mimeType, name: fileObject.name, title: text}
```

**ApiConfigAxios.js**

```
export const MultiPartAxios = (formData) => {
    return ApiConfigMultiPartAxios = axios.create({            
        baseURL: website,    
        withCredentials: true,    
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",           
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',                        
            "Authorization": `Basic ${base64data}`,        
        },        
    });
}
```

**ApiAxios.js**

```
export const ApiUpload = async (param) => {     
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', param);
   
    if (param.case === 1) {        
        const response = await MultiPartAxios(formData).post('/ApiUpload');                                             
        return response.data;     
    }
};
```

But I got error :

```
Object {
  "error": "Request failed with status code 500",
}
undefined
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The correct way to do it is this example :

**ApiConfigAxios.js**

```
export const ApiConfigMultiPartAxios = axios.create({            
    baseURL: website,    
    withCredentials: true,           
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",           
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',                        
        "Authorization": `Basic ${base64data}`,        
    },        
});
```

**ApiAxios.js**

```
export const ApiUpload = async (param) => {     
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', {
        uri: param.file,        
        type: param.mimeType,
        name: param.name,
    });
    
    formData.append('title', param.title);
    formData.append('case', param.case);
        
    
    if (param.case === 1) {        
        const response = await ApiConfigMultiPartAxios.post('/ApiUpload', formData);                 
        return response.data;     
    }
    
};
```